# How do I animate a scale css property using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I am trying to have a circle div with the class of "bubble" to pop when a button is clicked using jQuery. I want to get it to appear from nothing and grow to its full size, but I am having trouble getting it to work. heres my code:

HTML
    Show bubble
    ...
CSS

```
.bubble {
    transform: scale(0);
}
```

Javascript

```
 $('button').click(function(){
     $('.bubble').animate({transform: "scale(1)"}, 5000, 'linear');
 });
```

Comment: When do you want to scale the item? on hover , on page load or something else? please clear your question.

Comment: You can only animate numeric properties using jq `animate()` method. Your best bet is to toggle a class, handling the CSS transition

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can perform the transition using CSS and then just use Javascript as the 'switch' which adds the class to start the animation. Try this:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('.bubble').toggleClass('animate');
})
```

```css
.bubble {
  transform: scale(0);
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #C00;
  transition: all 5s;
}

.bubble.animate {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Toggle</button>
<div class='col-lg-2 col-md-2 well bubble'></div>
```

Comment: I see how this works, but haven't worked out how the animation timing and easing might be controlled. Any clues?

Comment: There's several CSS rules which you can use for this, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations) for more information, and try out the links on the left to read about the available rules.

Answer (score 21):

Currently you cannot use `animate` with the `transform` property [see here](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4171)

However you can add a css `transition` value and modify the css itself.

```js
var scale = 1;
setInterval(function(){
  scale = scale == 1 ? 2 : 1
  $('.circle').css('transform', 'scale('+scale+')')
}, 1000)
```

```css
.circle {
  margin: 20px auto;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Better go with CSS3 Animations. For animation at a frequent interval you can use with browser supporting prefixes(-webkit,-moz,etc.)-

```
@keyframes fullScale{
    from{
        transform:scale(0);
    }
    to{
        transform:scale(1);
    }
}
.bubble:hover{
    animation: fullScale 5s;
}
```

Refer this link-
**http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp**

Or the above solution by @Rory is also a good way to addclass on an attached event.

Answer (score 4):

Using the step callback and a counter. Here the counter is just the number 1.
'now' will be 0 to 1 over 5000ms.

```
$('.bubble').animate({transform: 1},
{duration:5000,easing:'linear',
step: function(now, fx) {
$(this).css('transform','scale('+now+')')}
})
```

Vanilla JS animate method  (supported in modern browsers, no IE)

https://drafts.csswg.org/web-animations-1/#the-animation-interface

```
$('.bubble').get(0).animate([{"transform": "scale(1)"}],
{duration: 5000,easing:'linear'})
```

Comment: This is the most useful when you are using dynamic positioning and animating to something that cannot be set with CSS

Answer (score 2):

You can use Velocity.js.
http://velocityjs.org/
For example:

```
$("div").velocity({
  "opacity" : 0,
  "scale" : 0.0001
},1800)
```