# Selecting only the current click (div) item in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to implement, grid system, where if I click on one of the divs, it zooms in while the other divs fades out.

How do I select both these elements separately so that

1. Current click div zooms in
2. Rest of the elements fades out

```js
var slider= $('.image_slide');

slider.on('click', function(){

    slider.css('opacity', 0);

});
```

```css
.slider_images{
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
}

.image_slide{
  padding:40px;
  display:block;
  background-color:#555; 
  width: 40%;
  margin-top:20px;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider_images>
           <a href= "#" class="image_slide">IMAGE 1 </a>
           <a href= "#" class="image_slide">IMAGE 2 </a>
           <a href= "#" class="image_slide">IMAGE 3 </a>
           <a href= "#" class="image_slide">IMAGE 4 </a>
        </div>
```

Here by clicking one of the divs, I would like the clicked div to zoom in while others disappear. How can Javascript and Jquery capture the current click event while selecting other elements to do another interaction?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code that you've tried so we can troubleshoot?

Comment: Please show what you have tried as well as a [mcve]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I animate a scale css property using jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35429935/how-do-i-animate-a-scale-css-property-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it using css and a little bit of js code without any jQuery. But you can adapt this code using jQuery features.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".item").forEach((element, n, all) => {
    element.addEventListener("click", () => {
        all.forEach(item => item.classList.remove("selected"))
        element.classList.add("selected");
    });
});
```

```css
.container{
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 20px;
  transition: 1s;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.item.selected {
  transform: scale(1.3);
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
</div>
```

Please note that `querySelectorAll`, `pointer-events`, `classList` may not be supported on old browsers, but you can fix it using older js approaches.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but here, could you please make the interaction in such a way that, once I click on one of these divs, it scales up while others fade away.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a click event to all the `div` and in the click event you select all of them and let them fade out. To get the one that got clicked to zoom in you can select it with `this` and just revert the fade out and do your zoom in.

```
document.getElementsByTag("div").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var divs = document.getElementsByTag("div"); //This are all your divs
    divs.foreach(function() {
       this.classList.remove("zoom-in"); //Could be that a element is already zoomed in what have to be reseted first
       this.classList.add("fades-out"); //Or However you do your fade out
    }
    this.classList.remove("fade-out");
    this.classList.add("zoom-in"); //Add your zoom effect
)};
```

I assume that you are doing your animations with `css` in this example.